# parseJSON working in one case and not in other

Tags: javascript, php, json

I was fetching some JSON data from server using ajay by passing an array into `json_enocode()` of PHP, it returned a JSON which is valid(checked on many online JSON debugger). But the `$.parseJSON()` of JS is not accepting it. Parser is throwing error(below) for one set of data while it works properly for other set of data.

> CONSOLE> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I tried removing all the elements of array one by one but it is not working even with a single element. Here are the data sets:

This is working:

```
[{"id":"54a3b103877c0","act_name":"ABC","profile_image":"[\"551d\"]"}]
```

While This is not:

```
[{"id":"2","user_id":"53b595a","review_for_id":"54f25","review_for_type":"city",
"r_title":"asfasas asd as","r_body":"a sdasda sdas dasdas das d","r_rating":"3",
"other_info":"","added":"2015-03-28 15:47:20","modified":"2015-03-28 15:47:20",
"f_name":"ABC","l_name":"XYZ","lives_in":"ABC"}]
```

PHP CODE:

Array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [user_id] => 53b595a
        [review_for_id] => 54f25
        [review_for_type] => city
        [r_title] => asfasas asd as
        [r_body] => a sdasda sdas dasdas das d
        [r_rating] => 3
        [other_info] => 
        [added] => 2015-03-28 15:47:20
        [modified] => 2015-03-28 15:47:20
        [f_name] => ABC
        [l_name] => XYZ
        [lives_in] => ABC
    )

)
```

PHP- Above array comes in $d

```
json_encode($d, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_QUOT)
```

Here is the Jquery for Ajax:

```
 $.get(url, '', function(d){
    var data = {};
    if(d != ''){
        data = $.parseJSON(d);
    }
    var acc = {};
    acc[sc_id] = data;
    console.log(acc);
});
```

Please help!

Comment: Can we have the `PHP` code?

Comment: I have added PHP Code.

Comment: Sorry Guys for wasting your time, the error was on the next parseJSON and I was debugging on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    var str = '[{"id":"2","user_id":"53b595a","review_for_id":"54f25","review_for_type":"city","r_title":"asfasas asd as","r_body":"a sdasda sdas dasdas das d","r_rating":"3","other_info":"","added":"2015-03-28 15:47:20","modified":"2015-03-28 15:47:20","f_name":"ABC","l_name":"XYZ","lives_in":"ABC"}]';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(str);
    alert(obj.id);
</script>
```

Comment: This code doesn't even work. It should be `alert(obj[0].id);` as `obj` is an array not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes from PHP the JSON data can be sent to AJAX call using json_encode function or plain text with JSON format and application/json header. So it's a better idea to check if the AJAX response is already an object or not.

```
var data = {};

if (typeof response !== 'object') {
    data = $.parseJSON(response);
} else {
    data = response;
}
```

This will prevent type error.